# Class available in activiti 6.0.0 but not in activiti 7.0.0.SR1

Tags: activiti

Following class available in activiti 6.0.0 but not in activiti 7.0.0.SR1.

```
 org.activiti.engine.FormService
 org.activiti.engine.form.FormProperty
 org.activiti.engine.form.TaskFormData
```

Can you suggest how we can find alternative of this class for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TaskRuntime API` or `ProcessRuntime API` to work with your process (simply autowire them). Follow [Documentation](https://activiti.gitbook.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/getting-started/getting-started-activiti-core) for more help and examples

Activiti is going through major changes to make it light and cloud native, and therefore removing unwanted classes out of the engine. Classes that have more efficient alternate solutions